# Building a package with devtools - throwing an error where "Author" and "Maintainer" fields are missing/empty despite being filled

Tags: r, package, devtools

In my DESCRIPTION file I have used the `AUTHORS@R` syntax to generate the `Author` and `Maintainer` fields, but in the R CMD Check process it keeps throwing an error message saying the fields are empty:

```
> checking for file 'bar/DESCRIPTION' ... ERROR
  Required fields missing or empty:
    'Author' 'Maintainer'
```

This was working previously so I don't know why it's not functioning now. I've saved the file, and rebuilt the pkg with "Clean and Rebuild". Alternatively I've tried filling the `Author` and `Maintainer` fields manually but that doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

You need to run `R CMD build` on the repo then `R CMD check` on the resulting tarball.

Answer (score 3):

A one liner which build and check the package.

```
R CMD build . && R CMD check $(ls -t . | head -n1)
```

a `.` means that sb already `cd` directory to the package one.
Both `.` (left and right) could be updated to PKGNAME if we are a one dir above.